# use python2 script as EXEC parameter of socat

Tags: docker, devops, socat, ctf

I'm trying to deploy a CTF challenge. so i have the following `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

socat -dd -T60 TCP-LISTEN:9002,reuseaddr,fork,su=game EXEC:/home/game/game.py,stderr
```

however when i build the docker image and run i get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /home/game/game.py
```

So my question is how to pass an argument like `python2 /home/game/game.py` to `EXEC`.

Thank you

Comment: when you run `docker build` it does not execute the entrypoint. i suggest you to post your Dockerfile and your `docker run` command

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]; where does that `/home/game` directory come from; is there a reason to use an obsolete and unsupported version of Python?